# How to change the allowed indentation level of an annotation array initialization child in Checkstyle?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, indentation, checkstyle

In a project I work on we use Checkstyle via the `maven-checkstyle-plugin`. We also use `springdoc-openapi-ui`, thus on the controllers we use the `@ApiReponses` annotation. It has a rather complex syntax, but it works well, so I wrote something like this on a controller:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(description = "foo",
                content = {
                        @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                schema = @Schema(implementation = UgyTableDataResponse.class)),
                        @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                                schema = @Schema(implementation = UgyTableDataResponse.class))
                })
})
```

However both the `@ApiResponse` and `@Content` annotations are marked by Checkstyle with **Checkstyle: 'annotation array initialization' child has incorrect indentation level 12, expected level should be 8.**

I would like to change the Checkstyle settings so that I can keep the annotations in this well readable format.

The indentation settings in my `checkstyle.xml` are:

```
<module name="Indentation">
        <property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
        <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
        <property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
        <property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
        <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="4"/>
        <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
    </module>
```

The plugin dependency in the POM is:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>validate</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I do not have access to the codebase anymore, but still, answers are welcome :) !

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the `arrayInitIndent` option in the configuration to 8 (because your code is indented using 8 spaces), or you can change the indentation level in your code to 4.

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(description = "foo",
        content = {
            @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                schema = @Schema(implementation = UgyTableDataResponse.class)),
            @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                schema = @Schema(implementation = UgyTableDataResponse.class))
        })
})
```